# Crosswalk not being added to Cordova Android App

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, crosswalk, apache-cordova

To increase compatibility with older Android devices (4.0+) for my Cordova App I am wanting to use the Crosswalk Webview instead of the device webview. I am using Cordova Tools (CLI 6.3.0) for Visual Studio (2015 - Update 3) and have added the Plugin "Crosswalk WebView Engine" using the plugins panel in the config.xml. However, when I start up the app, debug it and inspect the useragenet (using "navigator.userAgent" from the console) it is not reporting as running using the Crosswalk WebView Engine.

Now I have heard some people suggest that you remove the Android platform, install the plugin and then rebuild, but that isn't fixing it for me. Perhaps I am removing the Android platform incorrectly? (I am just deleting the folder from disk).

Is this a case of my build steps being incorrect? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After persisting with this problem, assuming it to be a problem with my set-up, I got it working.

The key was to update everything. I installed the latest Java JDK (v1.8) - Updated mt CLI version to 6.5.0 - Installed any updates using the Android Update Manager (I also updated some files within Android Studio itself) and then finally installed Crosswalk (2.3.0).

Works like a dream now.